# How to simplify the object code when two object has same set of keys in typescript

Tags: typescript, object

I have two variables which are having same set of object keys with different values like below.

```
let obj1 = {
 action: value1,
 item: value2
}

let obj2 = {
 action: value3,
 item: value 4;
}
```

I want to use obj1 and obj2 in two different places. Can you help me to simplify this above code using typescipt?

Comment: Sorry I am not clear on what you are asking.... There are two different objects why can't you use obj1 and obj2 in two different places??

Comment: That code is fairly small so I don't see that it's possible for anything to be "simpler".  Like, what are you envisioning?  `let obj1 = f(value1, value2)` and `let obj2 = f(value3, value4)`?  But that plus the `f` implementation will eat up any savings you have by abstracting the keys elsewhere.  Maybe I don't understand the question;  could you provide a self-contained [mre] that demonstrates your use case?  Right now I don't know what `value1`, `value2`, etc, are, nor do I see what needs to be simplified.

Comment: If you do decide to [edit] and want me to take another look, please notify me in a comment by mentioning @jcalz.  Good luck!